# What is the work of {{ }} in this html statement: <img alt="" src="~/content/Images/{{Imagename}}" />

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

While working on an MVC.Net web project I found below html statements on internet.

```
<div>
<div class="animate-show" ng-show="showAnim">
<img alt="" src="~/content/Images/{{Imagename}}" />
</div>
</div>
```

I implement it in my source code to display the images. But instead of displaying image, it simply displays {{Imagename}} as output. What is the mistake?

Comment: `{{Imagename}}` is an [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) used by [angularjs](https://angularjs.org)

Answer (score 0):

{{ImageName}} used by angularjs.

> ```
> <img alt="" src="~/content/Images/{{Imagename}}" />
> ```

You can display image like below.

> ```
> <img src='~/content/Images/@Model.ImagePropertyName' />
> ```